# Nginx conf file : Redirect from HTTP subdomain to HTTPS port

Tags: ssl, nginx

I'm brand new to Nginx and I have set a fresh install with Ajenti on port 8000.

I'm looking to have a subdomain point at Ajenti which is HTTPS but not use HTTPS anywhere else on the site. So that all of these things happen:

```
http://domain1.co.uk

http://sub.domain1.co.uk -> https://sub.domain1.co.uk

https://sub.domain1.co.uk -> https://domain1.co.uk:8000
```

I have gotten as far as:

```
http {
    index index.html;

    ssl_certificate      common.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key  common.key;

    server {
        listen 80;
        server_name www.domain1.co.uk;
        access_log logs/domain1.access.log main;

        root /var/www/domain1.co.uk/htdocs;
    }
    server {
        listen 80;
        server_name sub.domain1.co.uk;

        location / {
            proxy_pass https://127.0.0.1:8000/;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_buffering off;
        }
    }
}
```

How far off am I?

Thanks in advance

Mach

Comment: doesn't it do what you expect it to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, it would be:

```
http {
    index index.html;

    ssl_certificate      common.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key  common.key;

    # Redirect http://sub.domain1.co.uk to https://sub.domain1.co.uk
    server {
        listen 80;
        server_name sub.domain1.co.uk;

        return 301 https://sub.domain1.co.uk;
    }
    # Proxy pass https://sub.domain1.co.uk to http://127.0.0.1:8000/
    server {
        listen 443;
        server_name https://sub.domain1.co.uk;
        location / {
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000/;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_buffering off;
        }
    }
    # http://domain1.co.uk & www.domain1.co.uk
    server {
        listen 80;
        server_name domain1.co.uk
                    www.domain1.co.uk;
        access_log logs/domain1.access.log main;

        root /var/www/domain1.co.uk/htdocs;
    }        
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Few little tweaks had to be made, but got there in the end. HongTat more than pointed me in the right direction. Here's what I ended up with:

```
# Redirect http://sub.domain1.co.uk to https://sub.domain1.co.uk
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name sub.domain1.co.uk;

    return 301 https://sub.domain1.co.uk;
}

# Proxy pass https://sub.domain1.co.uk to http://127.0.0.1:8000/
server {
    listen 443;
    server_name sub.domain1.co.uk;

    client_max_body_size 20m;

    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/server.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/server.key;

    location / {
        proxy_pass https://127.0.0.1:8000/;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_buffering off;
    }
}

# http://domain1.co.uk & www.domain1.co.uk
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name domain1.co.uk
                www.domain1.co.uk;

    index index.html;

    root /var/www/domain1.co.uk/htdocs;
}
```

Followed a great guide for SSL
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-create-a-ssl-certificate-on-nginx-for-ubuntu-12-04/

And got my first nginx setup running as planned